# How do I disable OneDrive on Windows 11 permanently?

Tags: windows, onedrive

What are the steps to disable OneDrive permanently on the latest Windows 11?
I'd also like to erase any data that was previously backed up to OneDrive.

Comment: Permanently doesn't exist - sooner or later Microsoft manages to re-enable it.

Answer (score 1):

First, make backups of local files and folders.

Second, log into One Drive and delete files and folders.  This is why you made backups.

Finally, uninstall One Drive.
Settings, Apps, Installed Apps, scroll down to Microsoft One Drive.  Click in 3 dots  ...   and select Uninstall.

[image: Uninstall One Drive]

Here is a supporting article with more information.

[Remove or disable One Drive](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-disable-remove-onedrive/)

This will remove One Drive for the current feature cycle and the Windows updates therein.

It is always possible that Microsoft may install One Drive in a future Feature Update.

You can always just Unlink your Computer from One Drive and then it will not bother you.

Comment: Modifying your region settings, by doing [this](https://www.neowin.net/guides/here-is-a-simple-method-to-uninstall-edge-in-windows-10-and-11/), should allow you to permanently remove OneDrive. The article does explicitly mention OneDrive but the feature to support the new EU regulations applies to much more than Edge.